# installing Kernel headers for vagrant in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I want to install the Kernel headers in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Latest 64 bit (4.1.5-x86_64-linode61)) mounted in Linode Cloud hosting order to install vagrant,
but i an not able to find out the installed headers. No information typing:

```
root@localhost:~# dpkg -l | grep linux-headers
root@localhost:~#
```

I also tried using

```
root@localhost:~# sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.1.5-x86_64-linode61
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.1.5-x86_64-linode61'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`